# Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, memory-management

HI, I upload my php testing script to online vps server just now. The script used to parse a big size XML file(about 4M, 7000Lines). But my IE explorer show the online error message below.

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77 bytes) in /var/www/test/result/index.php  on line 26**

I am sure I already tested the php script on localhost successfully.

Is there any configuration need be enable/modify on my VPS? Such as php.ini or some setting for apache server?  I just verified there are about 200M memory usage are avaliable for my VPS. How can I fix this?

```
......
function startElementHandler ($parser,$name,$attrib){
    global $usercount;
    global $userdata;
    global $state; // Line #26; 
    //Debug
    //print "name is: ".$name."\n";
    switch ($name) {
        case $name=="_ID" : {
        $userdata[$usercount]["first"] = $attrib["FIRST"];
        $userdata[$usercount]["last"] = $attrib["LAST"];
        $userdata[$usercount]["nick"] = $attrib["NICK"];
        $userdata[$usercount]["title"] = $attrib["TITLE"];
        break;
        }

        ......

        default : {$state=$name;break;}
    }
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that one day your XML may outgrow your available memory...

Comment: which library are you using for parsing the file? If it's a big file you might want to consider using XMLReader over any other library, because it does not have to load the entire document into memory first.

Comment: @Gordon, I didn't use some library, I just found the tutorial 'codehelp.co.uk/php/xmlparse1.php' and practiced it with my XML file. And I would learn XMLReader later. Thanks.

Comment: The tutorial uses the XmlParser library. Try this approach instead: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-pullparsingphp.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP configuration is limiting PHP to only 16 megabytes of memory. You need to modify the `memory_limit` configuration directive in php.ini to increase it.

Look for the line in php.ini that looks like this:

```
memory_limit = 16M
```

...and change to to a large value (`16M` = 16 megabytes, you could increase it to something like `64M` for 64 megabytes, et cetera). If you can't find any line like that, add it.

If you prefer to only increase it on a per-script basis, you can also use `ini_set()` to change the value for that script only.

Comment: I think it would be better to set it larger only for this file, but leave the lower value for default config.

Comment: @Dav, I modified the value to 64M, and it works well. Later I would learn more PHP & XML knowledge and imporve my code.

@All, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [memory_get_peak_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) to find out which part of the program is eating your memory.

Answer (score 2):

Use a SAX parser instead of a DOM parser, and you won't run out of memory. DOM occupies 8-10 times the memory that the actual document stream does, whereas SAX has a reasonable constant overhead regardless of document size.

Answer (score 1):

```
ini_set("memory_limit","XXM");
```

please notice that some servers prevent this from working (though in a VPS this shouldn't be an issue, it's mostly a web hosting problem).

edit: instead of "`XX`" write the actual size, such as `128M`

Comment: +1 If you can then use this just for the code that needs the extra memory rather than making it global.

Comment: @Lo'oris, I tried to inserted `ini_set("memory_limit","128M");` to my index.php file. But it still can't work. showed the same error message. I guess maybe my VPS can't support the function. I can only choice modify php.ini and reboot my web service :-(. Thank you.
`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have specified the correct acceptable settings for:

- `file_uploads`
- `upload_max_filesize`
- `max_input_time`
- `memory_limit`
- `max_execution_time`
- `post_max_size`

You can call the `phpinfo()` function to find the location of your `php.ini` file, it will also tell you the current values for the following settings that you need to modify.

You could use the `ini_set` function to set some of those values from within your script too.

**SEE:**

**[Howto optimize your PHP installation to handle large file uploads.](http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php)**

Answer (score 1):

It is dirty but in some cases with large XML files it is faster to get the values via regular expressions! And if it is a well formatted XML there should be no problem!

pseudo code:

```
preg_match('+<title>(.*)</title>+', $xml_content, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

for shared hosting put this line to you index.php

```
ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
```