# Getting: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted

Tags: php

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes).

Thats the error i get when i try to upload a image on around 2,94 mb.

When i upload a image on 100kb and so it works fine. Why is this?

How can i make a restriction, so if you upload over xx bytes then you will get error that its too big, so i dont get that fatal error.

i started doing this at the form

```
$max_file_size = 8388608; 
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size ?>">
```

Here's my file upload:

```
<?php  
include "dbc.php";

$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'images/profilePhoto/';

$uploadForm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'editProfile.php';

$uploadSuccess = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'home.php';

$fieldname = 'file';


// possible PHP upload errors
$errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded', 
                2 => 'html form max file size exceeded', 
                3 => 'file upload was only partial', 
                4 => 'no file was attached');

// check the upload form was actually submitted else print form
isset($_POST['submit'])
    or error('You need to upload a profilephoto, no?', $uploadForm);

// check for standard uploading errors
($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0)
    or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);

// check that the file we are working on really was an HTTP upload
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);

// validation... since this is an image upload script we 
// should run a check to make sure the upload is an image
@getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('only image uploads are allowed', $uploadForm);

// make a unique filename for the uploaded file and check it is 
// not taken... if it is keep trying until we find a vacant one
$now = time();
while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))
{
    $now++;
}

// now let's move the file to its final and allocate it with the new filename
makeThumbnail($_FILES[$fieldname],  122, 160, $v[id]); 
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
    or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);
$filnamn =  $now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE users_profile SET photo = '$filnamn' WHERE uID = '$v[id]'") or die(mysql_error());
// If you got this far, everything has worked and the file has been successfully saved.
// We are now going to redirect the client to the success page.
echo "Du har nu bytt profillbild!";
// make an error handler which will be used if the upload fails
function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5)
{
    header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");
    echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"'."\n".
    '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'."\n\n".
    '<html lang="en">'."\n".
    '   <head>'."\n".
    '       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">'."\n\n".
    '       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">'."\n\n".
    '   <title>Upload error</title>'."\n\n".
    '   </head>'."\n\n".
    '   <body>'."\n\n".
    '   <div id="Upload">'."\n\n".
    '       <h1>Upload failure</h1>'."\n\n".
    '       <p>An error has occured: '."\n\n".
    '       <span class="red">' . $error . '...</span>'."\n\n".
    '       The upload form is reloading</p>'."\n\n".
    '    </div>'."\n\n".
    '</html>';
    exit;
} // end error handler
?>
```

MakeThumbnail function()

```
function makeThumbnail($file, $thumbSizeWidth, $thumbSizeHeight, $user) {
    if ($file['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        // something blew up
        // so handle error condition
        // 
        // error codes documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
        die();
    }

    $path_thumbs = "images/profilePhoto/thumbs/";
    $allowed_types = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/bmp', 'image/png', 'image/gif');

    $imageinfo = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']); // get image info
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = $imageinfo;

    if ($imageinfo === FALSE) {
        die("Uhoh. Unable to read uploaded file");
    }

    if (!in_array($imageinfo['mime'], $allowed_types)) {
        die("Sorry, images of type {$imageinfo['mime']} not allowed");
    }

    $rand_name = rand(0, 999999999); // this isn't particularly well done, but ...

    // create thumbnail
    switch($imageinfo['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/jpg':
            $new_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
            $file_ext = '.jpg';
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $new_img = imagecreatefromgif($file['tmp_name']);
            $file_ext = '.gif';
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $new_img = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']);
            $file_ext = '.png';
            break;
        default:
            die("Uhoh. How did we get here? Unsupported image type");
    }

    $imgratio = $height / $width;


        $newwidth = $thumbSizeWidth;
        $newheight = $thumbSizeHeight;

    $resized_img = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($resized_img, $new_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    $thumb_name = $rand_name . $file_ext;
    $thumb_path = $path_thumbs . '/' . $rand_name . $file_ext;
    imagejpeg($resized_img, $thumb_path);

mysql_query("UPDATE users_profile SET photo_thumb = '$thumb_name' WHERE uID = '$user'") or die(mysql_error());

    imagedestroy($resized_img);
    imagedestroy($new_img);

    return($thumb_name);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772198/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-exhausted is one of many posts that are asking the same problem

Comment: Please show some actual PHP code and what you are doing with the file upload.

Comment: Ok i will include the file upload script now

Comment: I think we need to see the makeThumbnail function too

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel If the OP is hitting a memory usage limit, and the makeThumbnail function is doing the memory intensive work then it makes sense to be able to see it, no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHp - memory error when resizing a PNG image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722352/php-memory-error-when-resizing-a-png-image)

Comment: Yeah, you need to increase your memory limit, or limit allowed size of uploaded images.

Comment: @Simon weren't it was obvious just from question title? If you want to ask something from the OP, you'd better ask to **always post exact copy of error message**, not just a stub. A single error  message will tell you a lot more than 100kb of code

Comment: It was obvious that the OP was hitting the memory limit - it wasn't obvious what the makeThumbnail function was doing. If the function was needlessly eating 10's of MB's of memory then upping the limit is not the correct answer, fixing the memory leak would have been.

Comment: Why do i need to increase memory limit when it only upload 3 Mb?

Comment: @Karem: The file size you upload does not seem to be the problem, but the memory which is consumed later on.

Comment: Because it's not the size on disk that dictates how much memory is required when processing the image with GD. It is the physical dimensions (i.e number of pixels) that will have the largest impact when creating the thumbnail.

Comment: Ok just did ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); , works fine now, but is 256M too much? and couldnt this be abused?

Comment: How much is too much depends on your server and your expected usage. If you're allowing large images to be uploaded then you will need a large memory limit. But if that usage is high and has a negative impact on the server performance then you could consider limiting the size of the upload

Comment: @Karem: or use -1 to let php be able to get as much memory as needed, but as stated further down to do it in good practice - a good analysis will enable you to minimize your memory usage

Comment: Right now the limit of the images is 6MB, is 256M memory_limit enough for that?

Comment: We can't tell you - the memory limit covers the entire PHP script which includes the image processing. You'll have to test with various images and see how much memory is used.

Comment: ok thank you i accepted your answer, as for helping through here in the comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like it's the overall [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), not the upload limit. Are you processing the image once uploaded with GD?

If so, this will be much more memory intensive on larger images if you're doing a lot of post processing on the uploads - in this case try upping the [memory limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), if you're doing something much more straight forward then there is probably another cause for the large memory usage...

Comment: Why the down vote? Looking at the comments in the question, this appears to have been the correct solution and fixed the OP's issue?

Answer (score 0):

very simple
Create a file called "`php.ini`" in the "`wp-admin`" folder of wordpress install.

Add the following text to the file:

```
memory_limit = 256M ;
```